# Out-of-line definition of 'TableCache' does not match any declaration in 'leveldb::TableCache'

Tags: c++, xcode, cocoapods, swift5, leveldb

I am having this issue in my cocoa pods file (leveldb-library), I don't know enough about C++ to be able to resolve it, however it appears to be a simple semantics error. I have just converted my Xcode project to Swift 5 and am attempting to enable Mac catalyst app support. I believe the other two issues are a result of the first issue and not independent issues.

The three error messages are namely;

ln 32: Out-of-line definition of 'TableCache' does not match any declaration in 'leveldb::TableCache'

ln 37: Reference to type 'const leveldb::Options' could not bind to an lvalue of type 'const leveldb::Options *'

ln 64: Indirection requires pointer operand ('const leveldb::Options' invalid)

Rightly or Wrongly I will include the whole file just incase the error lies elsewhere.

```
// Copyright (c) 2011 The LevelDB Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file. See the AUTHORS file for names of contributors.

#include "db/table_cache.h"

#include "db/filename.h"
#include "leveldb/env.h"
#include "leveldb/table.h"
#include "util/coding.h"

namespace leveldb {

struct TableAndFile {
  RandomAccessFile* file;
  Table* table;
};

static void DeleteEntry(const Slice& key, void* value) {
  TableAndFile* tf = reinterpret_cast<TableAndFile*>(value);
  delete tf->table;
  delete tf->file;
  delete tf;
}

static void UnrefEntry(void* arg1, void* arg2) {
  Cache* cache = reinterpret_cast<Cache*>(arg1);
  Cache::Handle* h = reinterpret_cast<Cache::Handle*>(arg2);
  cache->Release(h);
}

TableCache::TableCache(const std::string& dbname,
                       const Options* options,
                       int entries)
    : env_(options->env),
      dbname_(dbname),
      options_(options),
      cache_(NewLRUCache(entries)) {
}

TableCache::~TableCache() {
  delete cache_;
}

Status TableCache::FindTable(uint64_t file_number, uint64_t file_size,
                             Cache::Handle** handle) {
  Status s;
  char buf[sizeof(file_number)];
  EncodeFixed64(buf, file_number);
  Slice key(buf, sizeof(buf));
  *handle = cache_->Lookup(key);
  if (*handle == NULL) {
    std::string fname = TableFileName(dbname_, file_number);
    RandomAccessFile* file = NULL;
    Table* table = NULL;
    s = env_->NewRandomAccessFile(fname, &file);
    if (!s.ok()) {
      std::string old_fname = SSTTableFileName(dbname_, file_number);
      if (env_->NewRandomAccessFile(old_fname, &file).ok()) {
        s = Status::OK();
      }
    }
    if (s.ok()) {
      s = Table::Open(*options_, file, file_size, &table);
    }

    if (!s.ok()) {
      assert(table == NULL);
      delete file;
      // We do not cache error results so that if the error is transient,
      // or somebody repairs the file, we recover automatically.
    } else {
      TableAndFile* tf = new TableAndFile;
      tf->file = file;
      tf->table = table;
      *handle = cache_->Insert(key, tf, 1, &DeleteEntry);
    }
  }
  return s;
}

Iterator* TableCache::NewIterator(const ReadOptions& options,
                                  uint64_t file_number,
                                  uint64_t file_size,
                                  Table** tableptr) {
  if (tableptr != NULL) {
    *tableptr = NULL;
  }

  Cache::Handle* handle = NULL;
  Status s = FindTable(file_number, file_size, &handle);
  if (!s.ok()) {
    return NewErrorIterator(s);
  }

  Table* table = reinterpret_cast<TableAndFile*>(cache_->Value(handle))->table;
  Iterator* result = table->NewIterator(options);
  result->RegisterCleanup(&UnrefEntry, cache_, handle);
  if (tableptr != NULL) {
    *tableptr = table;
  }
  return result;
}

Status TableCache::Get(const ReadOptions& options,
                       uint64_t file_number,
                       uint64_t file_size,
                       const Slice& k,
                       void* arg,
                       void (*saver)(void*, const Slice&, const Slice&)) {
  Cache::Handle* handle = NULL;
  Status s = FindTable(file_number, file_size, &handle);
  if (s.ok()) {
    Table* t = reinterpret_cast<TableAndFile*>(cache_->Value(handle))->table;
    s = t->InternalGet(options, k, arg, saver);
    cache_->Release(handle);
  }
  return s;
}

void TableCache::Evict(uint64_t file_number) {
  char buf[sizeof(file_number)];
  EncodeFixed64(buf, file_number);
  cache_->Erase(Slice(buf, sizeof(buf)));
}

}  // namespace leveldb
```

Thank you for any help you would be able to provide.

**EDIT:** Here is (I believe) the requested header file.

```
// Copyright (c) 2011 The LevelDB Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file. See the AUTHORS file for names of contributors.
//
// Thread-safe (provides internal synchronization)

#ifndef STORAGE_LEVELDB_DB_TABLE_CACHE_H_
#define STORAGE_LEVELDB_DB_TABLE_CACHE_H_

#include <stdint.h>

#include <string>

#include "db/dbformat.h"
#include "leveldb/cache.h"
#include "leveldb/table.h"
#include "port/port.h"

namespace leveldb {

class Env;

class TableCache {
 public:
  TableCache(const std::string& dbname, const Options& options, int entries);
  ~TableCache();

  // Return an iterator for the specified file number (the corresponding
  // file length must be exactly "file_size" bytes).  If "tableptr" is
  // non-null, also sets "*tableptr" to point to the Table object
  // underlying the returned iterator, or to nullptr if no Table object
  // underlies the returned iterator.  The returned "*tableptr" object is owned
  // by the cache and should not be deleted, and is valid for as long as the
  // returned iterator is live.
  Iterator* NewIterator(const ReadOptions& options, uint64_t file_number,
                        uint64_t file_size, Table** tableptr = nullptr);

  // If a seek to internal key "k" in specified file finds an entry,
  // call (*handle_result)(arg, found_key, found_value).
  Status Get(const ReadOptions& options, uint64_t file_number,
             uint64_t file_size, const Slice& k, void* arg,
             void (*handle_result)(void*, const Slice&, const Slice&));

  // Evict any entry for the specified file number
  void Evict(uint64_t file_number);

 private:
  Status FindTable(uint64_t file_number, uint64_t file_size, Cache::Handle**);

  Env* const env_;
  const std::string dbname_;
  const Options& options_;
  Cache* cache_;
};

}  // namespace leveldb

#endif  // STORAGE_LEVELDB_DB_TABLE_CACHE_H_
```

Comment: The compiler is telling you that the definition of the `TableCache` constructor does not match the definition in the header (which you haven't shown us).  Maybe the 2nd parameter should be a reference?  [Edit] the question to include the header so we have a [mre].

Comment: Yeah the types in the declaration don't match the types in the definition. You did not edit any of these files yourself, did you? If so I am quite confused how you end up with mismatching files. This error would be immediately obvious when the code is compiled.

Comment: yeah, these are all source files added to the project via cocoapods I am guessing that the swift 5 conversion has converted one file and not the other.

Comment: The header file is a newer version and out-of-sync with the source file. The type of the declaration was changed from pointer to reference in [this commit](https://github.com/google/leveldb/commit/0fa5a4f7b1ad9dc16b705bcad1f3ca913f187325) in 2018. Your setup somehow ended up with mixed files from two different versions of the library.

Comment: I have deleted the entire leveldb-library and reinstalled it using ```pod update``` this seems to have resolved the version mismatch.